# Factory method to create a stream object (TCP, serial) from an URI

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, serial-port

### Context

I'm writing a C# program that communicates with some hardware, some via direct serial link, some via a TCP/IP socket.

Serial and TCP sockets are basically byte streams, especially if you don't deal with specific parameters like hardware flow control.

### Need

#### Common code: solved

For convenience, I'd like the same code to be able to switch between serial and TCP stream through simple configuration.

From a software design point of view, it's a matter of getting a common object in all cases and using only that in client code.  In C# one can get a `Stream` object from:

- an `http` URL (ref. [c# - Getting a Stream from an absolute path? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639379/getting-a-stream-from-an-absolute-path) )
- a SerialPort instance using the [SerialPort.BaseStream Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream(v=vs.110).aspx)
- a TcpClient instance using the [TcpClient.GetStream, méthode (System.Net.Sockets)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

So far so good.

#### Switch via configuration: missing link ?

Now how to represent the different cases in configuration ? URIs would be nice.

I'm aware that the URIs would not be portable, that's okay, a configuration file may be different on different platforms.

This discussion [Boost mailing page: Re: [boost] Re: [network] An RFC - updated](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2005/04/84617.php) mentions how a URL can represent such streams:

```
server.address=tcp4:/www.example.com:5757
server.address=com1:/57600,n,8,1
```

[20-sim 4C Builds](http://www.20sim4c.com/builds.html) says:

```
serial://com1?baud=115200
```

like [Serial Connection Problem on IF2 with advanced BR... - Intermec Community](http://community.intermec.com/t5/RFID-Development/Serial-Connection-Problem-on-IF2-with-advanced-BRI-Compact/td-p/19788).

---

Edit: reading [RFC 2396 - Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) it looks that the strings below would be more consistent:

```
serial://com1?baud=9600
serial:///dev/ttyS0?baud=9600
tcp://servernameorip:port
```

(End edit)

---

It would be nice to have a configuration file mention an URI with tcp or serial parameters and have code instantiate the correct concrete class.  In design patterns parlance this is called a factory method.

It would be used like this:

```
Stream mystream1=MyFactoryClass.GetStream("com1:/57600,n,8,1");
Stream mystream2=MyFactoryClass.GetStream("tcp4:/www.example.com:5757");
```

I can't find this on the internet or documentation.  URIs mentioning serial ports seem rare, another example: [Using Network Printers - CUPS.org](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/network.html)

#### Question

Does anyone know if such an open-source factory class already exists ?

It's not that long to do, but if it already exists it's better not to reinvent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not exist, but I believe the built-in `Uri` class supports custom schemes.

Consider doing it like the .NET Framework often does. The config file would specify a type name and a few string arguments. I don't see the need for URIs here.

Comment: (1) Thanks. I might extend the URI class for code clarity. Ref [1](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/writing-your-own-uriparser) and [2](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/writing-your-own-uriparser-part-2-implementing-getcomponents/). (2) TCP and serial string arguments differ so it smells. .NET style ? [connection strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx), [strong name references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s1sx4kfb(v=vs.80).aspx) or were you thinking of something different ? Any reference ?

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. WCF has a very strong extensibility model. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx. Look how you can define custom types and give parameters to their instantiations in web.config.

Comment: I ended up doing a plain factory method receiving a string (not even an URI) and instantiating the SerialPort or TcpClient then returning the stream.  (Next step is: the TCP stream is sometimes interrupted, I might as well return some Stream factory object that can reconnect and provide another stream.)